# How to get variable environment from parent user?

Tags: su, environment

I need to know how it's possible to get environment variable from a parent user after su? For example if I'm evan user and I have variable $DISPLAY=:10.0, then I use "su -" to go to root user, how could I get the $DISPLAY variable from parent evan user?

Comment: Looks like a XY [problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Might tell us, why you need the display in root...

Comment: very well. I need to su in root to run a script, but later in script I have to launch xclock which is not working because something like display problem is not inherited from original user. If I set manually the DISPLAY as original user evan, everything works nice, but the display value is changing.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd look at [xhost](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108784/running-gui-application-as-another-non-root-user)

Usually I could also manage to get some GUI open as root (depending on the linux distro) with defining

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

in my script.

That the display id is changing as you have written is unknown to me.

Comment: as soon as the DISPLAY is different than original opened one DISPLAY=:10.0 it does not work in same session.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by using following lines:

```
prev_user=$(pstree -lu -s $$ |grep --max-count=1 -o '([^)]*)' |head -n 1 | sed 's/[()]//g')
inherit_display=$(xauth -f /home/$prev_user/.Xauthority list|tail -1|cut -d/ -f2|cut -d ' ' -f1)

export DISPLAY="$inherit_display"
```

prev_user - is getting the previous user (parent user) from which I used su

inherit_display - get exactly the value of DISPLAY for parent user

finally I export the value to my new DISPLAY for root.

works like a sharm.